# How to access a special field in a subquery?

Tags: python, django, subquery

I have an image field in Django, but I'm using an [StdImage](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage) field:

```
class Photo(TimestampedModel):
    image = StdImageField(upload_to='photos', variations={'thumbnail': (200, 200), 'large': (1024, 1024)})
```

Normally, in a template I can use the following to access a 'variation':

```
<img alt="" src="{{ object.myimage.thumbnail.url }}"/>
```

However, I am using a subquery to retrieve the latest photo for an article (there could be many photos, or none) and I have no other way than to retrieve the image as a single value (as I can't retrieve multiple values in a subquery).

```
newest_photo = Photo.objects.filter(industry__type=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date')
list = Article.objects.filter(published=True).annotate(image=Subquery(newest_photo.values('image')[:1]))
```

This all works well. Except for one thing. I am only able to retrieve the regular image, not the variation (which I would normally access by  `object.image.thumbnail.url`). Any  idea how to access this variation?

Comment: did you try myimage['thumbnail'].url? if not then maybe you have to get the url in the view, and set it as a context variable.

Comment: Yeah I tried but the subquery field is returned as a plain string, so nothing else is available in that field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can avoid subqueries in this situation and keep it simple.

```
#view.py

newest_photo = Photo.objects.filter(industry__type=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date')[:1]
articles = Article.objects.filter(published=True)
article_list = []

for article in list:
  article_list.append({
    #here you add the article fields you want from the model
    #or 'article':article.to_dict()
    'img':newest_photo,
    #just to be sure add the url here as well
    'thumbnail_url':newest_photo.thumbnail.url
  })
context = {'articles':article_list}
```

Now you can send it as context and access the url with `article.img.thumbnail.url` or `article.thumbnail_url`

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't this mean a performance hit? If I have 200 records then I would loop over them twice... first in the view and then again in the template. Secondly, and more importantly, wouldn't this mean that there would be 201 database queries? One for the original query (articles), and then one for each of the items in the articles list (in order to define newest_photo)?

Comment: I assume each article has some reference to an image, if so there would it would be possible to limit the queries to 2 total. One for the article instances, and the other for the images. Once the webserver has gotten a response the list generation would not take long as this is simply assigning strings to  200+ variables. Please provide more information on the models and I can adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a lot of Photo objects per Article? If no, the best way is to use prefetch_related to prefetch all Photos (order them using Prefetch object),  and then get the first with simple index

```
list(article.photos.all())[0]
```

Note that you have to use list(),  either way Django will decide to make another query,  instead of using already prefetched objects. You can add a method to Article (latest_photo)  to do this and call prefetch_related in view,  then use the method in template.